# Modelling problem - Networked devices with commands

Tags: oop, modeling

I encountered a head scratching modelling problem today:

We are modelling a physical control system composed of **Devices** and **NetworkDevices**. Any example of a **Device** is a TV. An example of a **NetworkDevice** is an IR transceiver with Ethernet connection.

As you can see, to be able to control the TV over the internet we must connect the **Device** to the **NetworkDevice**. There is a one to many relationship between **Device** and **NetworkDevice** i.e. TV only has one **NetworkDevice** (the IR transceiver), but the IR transceiver may control many **Devices** (e.g. many TVs).

So far no problem.

The complicated bit is that every **Device** has a collection of **Commands**. The type of the **Command** (e.g **IrCommand**, **SerialCommand** - N.B. not currently modelled) *depends* on the type of **NetworkDevice** that the **Device** is connected to.

In the current legacy system the **Device** has a collection of generic **Commands** (no typing) where fields are "interpreted" depending on the **NetworkDevice** type.

How do I go about modelling this in OOP such that:

- You can only ever add a **Command** of the appropriate type, given the **NetworkDevice** the **Device** is attached to?
- If I change the NetworkDevice the Commands collection changes to the appropriate type
- Make it so the API is simple/elegant/intuitive to use

Comment: Please clarify, is the set of commands always the same, but implementation is different based on the NetworkDevice? Or are there commands that are only available on certain NetworkDevices?

Comment: No. The set of commands is completely customizable- the network device needs "compatible" commands. For example the IR NetworkDevice will need IR codes for the comamnds. A serial NetworkDevice might need valid serial codes

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). The idea would be to give the `Device` a factory for creating `Commands`. The type of the factory would depend on the type of the `NetworkDevice`. So, if a `Device` is connected to an `IR-Controller`, it will get an `IRCommandFactory`.

Comment: So if I disconnect from IR and connect to Serial the factory will change? I am not sure yet whether the business requires the commands to be deleted when you plug into a new NetworkDevice